# Logging changes for every column in a table

Tags: database-design

I am busy creating a system where I need to keep track of every change in the system. In other words, when a column in the database is changed, I need to know what table, which column, when the change was made, by which user, from what value, to what value.

My first thought was to create a second table for each table for logging purposes, containing fields like column_name, updated_by, updated_on, from_value, to_value (keeping the from_value and to_value fields as strings for simplicity). This, however, will essentially create a duplicate of the database.

My second option would be to create a massive table of a similar type (table_name, column_name, updated_by, updated_on, from_value, to_value) for all the tables, yet this will result in an unmanageable table, as changes will be happening frequently.

Both these option have the same problem, that I am unsure how to reference the columns of a table, and worst of all, how do I handle a change in column names later in the life of the application.

Any thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, I would probably store a database object ID instead of a string with the name of the column/table/etc, which might solve the renaming columns issue (if the ID stays the same, not sure if it does). Otherwise, great question, I always dreaded having to do something like this myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here:

- you're not constrained by disk space
- you have a non-trivial data model
- you need to be able to report your audit/history information in a human-readable format
- you're not working with extreme performance or scalability requirements
- the audience for your audit data is business user level, not technical level.

In that case, the best solution I know is to make "history" a first-class concept in your design. The [link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/) GregL quoted has a good description of this; my simpler implementation basically means having "valid_from" and "valid_until" and "operator_id" columns on every table, and to use "is_valid" rather than the delete operation.

This is better than auditing changes to separate tables, because it allows you to create a complete picture of your data at any given point in history, complete with all the relationships between tables, using the same logic as your regular data access code. That, in turn, means you can create reports using standard reporting tools, answering questions like "which operator changed the prices for all products in the food category", "how many products were less than $100 on 1 Jan?" etc.

It does consume more space, and it does make your database access logic more complex. It also doesn't play nicely with ORM solutions.

Comment: This has been a favourite option, yet it doesn't suit my needs exactly. For example, on a Product I want to have a tab where the users can see a table with all changes made to that Product, when and by whom. The example in the [link above](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/) and [here](http://www.indywebshop.com/bestpractices/2006/07/28/leaving-an-audit-trail-in-your-database/) imply that I'd have to do a row by row comparison in order to list a table of the history of changes

Comment: Indeed - but this is (mostly) an issue for the user interface. It's not hugely difficult to write a library function to diff two rows, column by column; depends, of course, on your front-end code. In this model, you would show one record for each change; you could make each column that changes between rows green. That's a lot more meaningful (in my view) than "user x changed price from y to z", because changes tend to come in groups - changing price and description at the same time, for instance.

Comment: I suppose it could work like that. I was going to have a series for rows in the table (on the front end) with a whole lot of "user x changed price from y to z", etc. etc. In addition the app will have close to 100 tables and I'm dreading a second table for each one. And some tables have close to 50 columns

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered that the term for this sort of functionality is called "auditing". A quick Google search for "database design full auditing" yielded the following interesting links - might be worth a read:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/

http://www.restfuldevelopment.net/david-kawliche/writing/time-after-time/

[Best implementation for fully auditable data model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859492/best-implementation-for-fully-auditable-data-model)

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Puzzles/anaudittrailgenerator/2067/

They were just the ones that stood out to me, you might find better links now that you know the key word of "audit".

Comment: Thanks for the articles. I looked around and found some more, but it's along the same lines as the already provided answeres

Answer (score 1):

Check my [answer for the question "history rows management in database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715811/history-rows-management-in-database/715914#715914)
It describes the solution I used with pros and cons of that approach.

Basically, it's one massive table, but changes are recorded as XML in one string field.

**Edit:**

I did not have problems with changing column names, since every change is one XML string.
Most of the times I had to dig into history, question was "who and when changed that one particular record", so I could select small number of records with the same Id.
Problem with this approach is if you need to find all records where some value occurred. It requires full text search on whole table and that is very slow.
You need to analyze possible search scenarios and then pick best solution.

There is one more thing to consider - history records will never be changed, so you can have another database that can keep copy of history records cross indexed for fast searches. Create a automatic service that will from time to time copy history records from live database.

Comment: The info was useful but I still have the problem in that if I change the column name of a table, I'll have no way of knowing what it was before so I can perform searches (unless I perform mass renames in the history table). This means I'll have to keep a log of changing column names. As for the need, I agree. It's a "very important feature" that is hardly used. The problem is, that when it is needed, it's usually due to a court case that results in money changing hands.

Comment: The XML option is not very good for me, as the changes made to the tables will need to be available via a tab, so that at any time, any user will be able to see who changed what.

Answer (score 0):

This would be kinda weird but you could add a "InsertedOnTimestamp" column to each table as a 2nd primary key. Then never allow users to update the tables and create views that only show the most recent record.

```
Select * From Table
    Inner Join (Select ID, Max(InsertedOnTimestamp) as LastestRecord From Table Group By ID) as Latest 
    On Table.ID = LatestID AND Table.InsertedOnTimestamp = Latest.LatestRecord
```

Sounds messey as hell, but an idea none the less...

Comment: It's not a bad idea. The problem comes in, though, when you have a table with 50 columns and you only have a change in one of the columns. This method would unnecessarily create a massive table with duplicate data.