# Maintaining UserLog for each user in LAN based Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I have one application which is LAN based and there is one concept of maintaining each user's activity, that userlog should only be visible to Admin only, and the record for each user's activity of insert, update and delete to be maintained.

I have developed whole application but I am still confused how to develop this concept in my application.

Comment: Does the application use a central database? If yes, just store all log records there.

Comment: I have central as well as companywise database, and the problem i am facing is that i have master-transaction table and when i maintain tables with insert update of master table than it is ok but when record will be in update mode at that time, i am deleteing first all data from transaction related to master record and inserting new records from transaction grid, so how can Admin understand that Transaction entries are updated by so so person???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for history recording in the database.
[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950768/logging-changes-for-every-column-in-a-table) has good answers and additional links to get you started.

Comment: You are almost to my Problem but dear, these all things i have applied to my all tables in DB, but the things are related to my master transaction tables, like i have two tables: BrandMaster and BrandTransaction,
for adding records in Transaction i am using Gridview, Now my problem is when user will be in update mode, than i am first deleteing old records from transaction and than inserting new records from grid. In this case log will me maintained as delete and insert case and i want to maintain case as update case, that much how can i do